# Migrate pd.ewma from pandas 0.17.0 to 1.1.2

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to port this line of code from Python 2.7/Pandas 0.17.0 to Python 3.7/Pandas 1.1.2:

*python 2.7 / pandas 0.17.0*
returnVar = pd.ewma(varSeries, span = varSpan)

*python 3.7 / pandas 1.1.2.*
returnVar = varSeries.ewm(span = varSpan)

In the legacy code, the return type is `pandas.core.series.Series` whereas in the migrated code the return type is `pandas.core.window.ewm.ExponentialMovingWindow`

How do I fix this so that I get the exact same return value and type?

*python 2.7 / pandas 0.17.0*

```
>>>type(varSeries)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>>type(varSpan)
<type 'numpy.float64'>
>>>varSpan
3.0
>>>varSeries
IndexDate
2002-01-07    347.98470
                 ...  
2020-09-29     89.11943
Name: SPGSCLP, dtype: float64
>>>
>>>returnVar = pd.ewma(varSeries,span=varSpan)
>>>type(returnVar)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>>returnVar
IndexDate
2002-01-07    347.984700
                 ...  
2002-01-08    345.500633
Name: SPGSCLP, dtype: float64
```

*python 3.7 / pandas 1.1.2*

```
>>>returnVar = varSeries.ewm(span=varSpan)
>>>type(returnVar)
<class 'pandas.core.window.ewm.ExponentialMovingWindow'>
>>>returnVar
ExponentialMovingWindow [com=1.0,min_periods=1,adjust=True,ignore_na=False,axis=0]
```

Comment: I think you want `varSeries.ewm(span=varSpan).mean()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is indeed what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Erfan.

The ported code should be:

```
returnVar = varSeries.ewm(span=varSpan).mean()
```